# Where can I look up the namespaces for stylecop rules so that I can suppress them?

Tags: namespaces, stylecop, suppress

There seem to various questions asking specifically how to suppress particular stylecop warnings, for example:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules", "SA1202:ElementsMustBeOrderedByAccess"]
```

But where can I authoratively look to get the short name of the rule and (particularly) the namespace containing it. I have downloaded the stylecop project and looked at the project ruleset without finding anything useful. There seem to be some global rules prefixed SA, and I can't find a good reference on them.

This talks about suppressing rules, but doesn't lead to namespace information on SA rules
https://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2009/08/10/rule-suppressions.aspx?Redirected=true.

Documentation such as http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1202.html is deeply unhelpful in providing the rule category name, but not the actual namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any published documentation containing that namespaces, but you can certainly look it up in the source code.

https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/007dc67059b53cc5a94be676f17ad3ea8881d4ad/Project/Src/StyleCop.CSharp.Rules/OrderingRules.cs

From the file above you can see that fully qualified name for ordering rules would be **StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules**.

https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/007dc67059b53cc5a94be676f17ad3ea8881d4ad/Project/Src/StyleCop.CSharp.Rules/OrderingRules.xml

From this file you can get **shortname:longname** values. For ordering rules we can see that it would be **SA1202:ElementsMustBeOrderedByAccess**.